# Following multiple ID / Class rules in CSS

Tags: css, height, rules

I'm trying to have a scrolling banner on the index page which has multiple sub-properties but, the main property of:

```
height: 75vh;
```

On all following pages I would like the same banner to have all the other rules that apply to it, but only have the height different:

```
height: 30vh;
```

This would allow both banners to follow all the same rules for remaining mobile responsive - ie they both still come under the id="banner".

One easy fix for this would be to label one id="bannerX" and one id="bannerY" and then just copy all the subsequent CSS under the corresponding X or Y. For example:

```
#bannerX {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 40em;
    height: 75vh;
    position: relative;
}

    #bannerX input, #banner select, #banner textarea {
        color: #fff;
    }

    #bannerX a {
        color: #fff;
    }

    #bannerX strong, #banner b {
        color: #fff;
    }

   and so on...
```

versus

```
#bannerY {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 40em;
    height: 30vh;
    position: relative;
}

    #bannerY input, #banner select, #banner textarea {
        color: #fff;
    }

    #bannerY a {
        color: #fff;
    }

    #bannerY strong, #banner b {
        color: #fff;
    }

   and so forth...
```

But that just leads to a duplication of a lot of CSS that is the exact same, just the original ID is changing one rule within it. This would work but just seems a really messy way around it. I'm sure there must be a better way of working this but I can't seem to make it work. I've tried adding in a class="banner-thick" or class="banner-thin" to each within their own section but that didn't seem to work either because then neither banner follows the original id="banner" rules because they're now id="bannerX" or id="bannerY"! I can't seem to make it work! Does anyone have an idea of how I can fix this?

I suspect there's a simple fix and I just can't see the wood from the trees!

Thanks all.

Comment: Just add `<style> #banner {height:75vh} </style>` after the stylesheet link on page 1.

Comment: use multiple class like this - `class="bannerX height1"` for 1st one. For 2nd one use `class="bannerX height2"`. Where height only holds value of heights. No need to use heights in bannerX.

Comment: Everyone's comments work. I must say though Mr Lister - that was, hands down, the easiest way to do it! I've just slotted the standard height into an editable region within the template file and then just changed it for the index page only. Sorted. Please write your comment in as a proper comment so that I can rate it as answered. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple class like this - `class="bannerX height1"` for 1st one. For 2nd one use `class="bannerX height2"`. Where height only holds the value of heights. No need to use heights in `bannerX`.

## CSS

```
.bannerX {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 40em;
    /*height: 75vh;*/ as we define different heights in height1 & height1 class
    position: relative;
}

.height1 {
    height: 75vh;
}

.height2 {
    height: 75vh;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div class="bannerX height1">
</div>


<div class="bannerX height2">
</div>
```